# TSQL Error when joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I get this error a lot when I am trying to join (probably because I have never been too great with them).

My stored procedure is pretty straight forward:

```
SELECT *
FROM   
   (SELECT DISTINCT 
        (A.whoAdded) AS whoAdded,
        COUNT(A.tag) AS totalTags,
        COUNT(DISTINCT A.data) AS totalSubmissions,
        COUNT(DISTINCT B.data) AS totalSearches,
        C.firstName AS firstName,
        C.lastName AS lastName,
        C.titleDesc AS titleDesc
    FROM
        Tags_Accounts AS A
    INNER JOIN
        Tags_Log AS B ON A.whoAdded = B.ntid
    INNER JOIN
        empTable AS C ON A.whoAdded = C.ntid
    WHERE    
        whoAdded = @ntid
    GROUP BY 
        whoAdded) AS a
FOR XML PATH ('profile'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

The error I get that is always similar is :

> Column 'empTable.FirstName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I was hoping if someone could point out why this query wont work or what I can do to fix it, I can fix all my other attempts that put me in the same spot.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you're including the first and last name, plus the title, without grouping by them. Either add them to the group, remove them from the select statement, or perform some aggregate on them.

Comment: I guess I was just a little unclear about when you add something to the group by clause

Comment: Two side notes: **(1)** if your column `C.firstName` is identical to the alias you're giving it (`AS firstName`), then that alias is really pointless and could just as well be avoided altogether. **(2)** I would recommend to use **more meaningful** table aliases rather than just `A`, `B` and `C` - use something that is more obvious: `Tags_Accounts AS ta`, `Tags_Logs AS tl`, `empTable AS e` or something like that! Make your query just that much more readable and more easily understandable!

Answer (score 1):

You're asking query to differentiate by name and description

```
                  C.firstName AS firstName,
                  C.lastName AS lastName,
                  C.titleDesc AS titleDesc
```

as well as

> whoAdded

so they need to be added to the group by clause so that the rows can collapse into the groups correctly.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT   DISTINCT (A.whoAdded) AS whoAdded,
                      count(A.tag) AS totalTags,
                      count(DISTINCT A.data) AS totalSubmissions,
                      count(DISTINCT B.data) AS totalSearches,
                      C.firstName AS firstName,
                      C.lastName AS lastName,
                      C.titleDesc AS titleDesc
    FROM     Tags_Accounts AS A
             INNER JOIN
             Tags_Log AS B
             ON A.whoAdded = B.ntid
             INNER JOIN
             empTable AS C
             ON A.whoAdded = C.ntid
    WHERE    whoAdded = @ntid
    GROUP BY 
             whoAdded,  
             C.firstName ,
             C.lastName ,
             C.titleDesc 
) AS a
FOR    XML PATH ('profile'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "GROUP BY" statement must include all columns that are not affected by aggregate functions (like SUM, COUNT, MAX, etc.). The following columns will need added to your GROUP BY C.firstName, C.lastName, C.titleDesc. Also, you should remove DISTINCT (A.whoAdded) entirely because correcting your GROUP statement will have this desired effect.

solution, fix your GROUP BY!

```
...
GROUP BY A.whoAdded, C.firstName, C.lastName, C.titleDesc
...
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use group by, your select should contain only grouped columns or agregated functions, so you'll need to group

```
 C.firstName AS firstName,
 C.lastName AS lastName,
 C.titleDesc AS titleDesc
```

too

use this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM   (SELECT   DISTINCT (A.whoAdded) AS whoAdded,
                          count(A.tag) AS totalTags,
                          count(DISTINCT A.data) AS totalSubmissions,
                          count(DISTINCT B.data) AS totalSearches,
                          C.firstName AS firstName,
                          C.lastName AS lastName,
                          C.titleDesc AS titleDesc
        FROM     Tags_Accounts AS A
                 INNER JOIN
                 Tags_Log AS B
                 ON A.whoAdded = B.ntid
                 INNER JOIN
                 empTable AS C
                 ON A.whoAdded = C.ntid
        WHERE    whoAdded = @ntid
        GROUP BY whoAdded,C.firstName,C.lastName,C.titleDesc) AS a
    FOR    XML PATH ('profile'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit what that phrase means "when you use group by, your select should contain only grouped columns or agregated functions, so you'll need to group " - I understand the change you made to it but a still a little unsure how it works

Comment: If a column is not part of an aggregate function (Sum, count, etc) and you want to see it, then you ned to include it in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aggregating other columns, obviously you need to use group by , to group columns together on which aggregation will be performed. 
just include this in your query:

```
Group by A.wholeadded, C.firstname,c.lastname,c.titledesc
```

Aggregations will be  performed on Groups.
Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

When You Use Group By You must Call of Columns that's used in select 
Like :

```
     select T.firstname,T.lastname,T.ID,Count(*) from personel
       Where Count(*) >1
         Group by T.firstname,T.lastname,T.ID
```